# Ant-Jmeter distributed Load Testing: Master does not send parameters to slave

Tags: ant, jmeter

when i make a run with ant task(ant -Dtest=test -DThreads_CE=10 -DRampUp_CE=10 -DLoop_CE=1):

Only 1 thread is started and I get an error for contained requests:

1. "Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException - Non HTTP response message: Network is unreachable: connect"
2. On debugging, I observed no parameters from my build.xml were reaching Slave machine. So every parameter defaults to "1"

But, when the same script is run through headless Jmeter(jmeter -n -t test.jmx -R 172.27.xx.xxx):
the script runs fine for all requests.

Firewall:OFF
Antivirus:OFF
GUI mode also runs fine with slave machines

I need to properly use the ant-jmeter task for this as I need Ant-jmeter HTML reports.
Could Someone shed some light on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor documentation of distributed load testing using Ant-jmeter mentions just to do a remoterun="true"...

But it turns out that a `remote="true"` attribute with each of the parameter present in your build.xml is mandatory for that value to be sent across to slave.

You'd guess doing `remoterun="true"` would alone work!

Hope it helps someone in need! :)

Comment: did you set it to target attribute or like separate property tag?

Comment: target attribute